# Deploy error in target sandbox; no ApexClass found

Tags: apex, sandbox, deployment

I am deploying a new apex class from Sandbox (SB1) to SB2. I have 1 profile, **ABC Service** profile. 
I get this error after Validating in Target sandbox SB2.

> In field: apexClass - no ApexClass named **OrderTrackingList** found in SB2

Shall I create the class in SB2 and then try deploying or how  should I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the new class have reference of OrderTrackingList class in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sandbox SB1, First go to Setup > Develop | Apex classes. There click on compile all classes. Check it all classes must be compiled.

As the error says ** OrderTrackingList** doesn't exist in Sandbox SB2. So you have two ways to deploy profile

1) Remove access to ** OrderTrackingList** for **ABC Profile** in SB1 and try deploy. Also remove all access to classes which don't exist on sandbox SB2. After that you can give access to that class.

2) Send ** OrderTrackingList** and all its dependencies with **ABC Profile**

you have to send all dependent components which don't exist on other environment.

Comment: thnx for the quick response. If I don't write test class can I deploy to another sandbox? Or test class is a must?

Comment: @MnZ you have to write test class if it isn't exist on SB1

Comment: i want to move the apex class from SB1 to SB2. I compiled successfully

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't provide the feedback. @Ashwani's solution worked, when I removed all access to that class in SB1 and then moved to SB2.